# How to override isEqual: for CLBeacon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, equality

### Background

I have a method, provided by a 3rd party library, that returns an array of `CLBeacons`.

```
- (void)beaconManager:(ESTBeaconManager *)manager
      didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons
             inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
```

This method is called at regular intervals and the array contains a list of the beacons that are in range. Objects in the array are not reused, *new beacon objects are sent each time*.

I'm adding and removing these objects to arrays based on their proximity.

---

### Question

How can I implement `isEqual:` for `CLBeacon` so that array methods like `containsObject:`, `removeObject:`, etc work without lots of extra implementation.

I can't subclass, because the `CLBeacon` is returned as a `CLBeacon`, I can't just cast it to my custom class.

I can't write a category because which `isEqual:` is called at runtime is undefined.

> If the name of a method declared in a category is the same as a method in the original class, or a method in another category on the same class (or even a superclass), the behavior is undefined as to which method implementation is used at runtime. This is less likely to be an issue if you’re using categories with your own classes, but can cause problems when using categories to add methods to standard Cocoa or Cocoa Touch classes.

<sup>[[Source]](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW4)</sup>

I'd really rather not resort to method swizzling.

Comment: Why do you need to implement a method on the class?

Comment: Could it work with if([your_array.containsObject:YOUR_BEACON]){ ... do your stuff} ?

Comment: In this case it's because of array methods like `[array containsObject:object]`. They use `isEqual:` internally

Comment: @LoVo, contains will return false without the `isEqual:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global function beaconsAreEqual that takes 2 CLBeacons as input and returns a bool.

Or do you specifically need to define the isEqual method? If so you might **have** to use method swizzling.

### Edit:

Alternately you could create a custom subclass of CLBeacon that overrides isEqual (and probably hash, if you want to use the NSArray method `contains`)

Then create a custom initializer for your class that takes a regular CLBeacon as input and copies the relevant info (UUID, major and minor version numbers are all you should need.)

Once you've done that you could take the beacons that come in from the location manager, convert them to your custom class, and save THOSE into your array and use them for your `contains` checks.

### Edit #2:

Another option would be to use the NSArray method `indexOfObjectPassingTest` instead of. That method takes a block as a parameter, and returns an integer index, or NSNotFound if the object can't be found.

### Edit #3:

It looks like there is no initializer for creating CLBeacon objects yourself. You'd have to create a data container object (subclass of NSObject) that saves the info from a CLBeacon. That would work just fine for checking if a beacon is already in your array

Comment: Specifically `isEqual:` so that array functions work without lots of extra implementation I'm afraid

Comment: I thought about making a "copy constructor" pattern, but the properties are readonly and the underlying variables aren't accessible.

Comment: It looks like there is no initializer for creating CLBeacon objects yourself. You'd have to create a data container object (subclass of NSObject) that saves the info from a CLBeacon. That would work just fine for checking if a beacon is already in your array,

Comment: That's an idea. I hadn't thought about using composition over inheritance. (y)